# Reading a file using a buffer

Tags: java, io

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question right, but I want to make some sort of lyrics player using subtitle files. As I also want to make it compatible with larger files (say 10.000 lines), it's not a good idea to load the file before you play it. This might cost a lot of time and unnecessary amounts of data stored on the RAM. That's why I want to load it the way for example online videos do (they store an amount of minutes on the RAM and discard that what's been played, all while playing). I believe this is called buffering.

My question was: are there any pre-made i/o classes inside java that allow this sort of thing? I know a lot of classes with buffer in their name, but I have little to no idea what they do or what they are different from other classes (without buffer in their name).

Comment: Not AFAIK in the standard Java API, but you can easily do something like that using, for example, a `Scanner` instance. You just call `readLine()` every time you want a next line, and you can discard previous lines by letting them go out of scope. By the way, most classes with 'buffer' in their name pre-load their data, which is exactly _not_ what you want.

Comment: In fact it's the other way around. Everything, that java offers to access files won't load the entire file into memory. InputStream, Reader and RandomAccessFile all load a limited pice into memory. It's completely up to whether to handle the data temporary, or put in a structre that persists in memory